# Amazon MWS - Don't understand how to generate HMAC

Tags: base64, sha256, hmac, amazon-mws

In the moment I'm struggling a little bit with the generation of HMAC for Amazon MWS.

I thought I understood how it works.

With the Scratchpad I generated a request. Scratchpad shows the string to sign and also the SHA 256 HMAC and the Base64 HMAC.
The string to sign consists of 4 lines like it's described in the docu.

There are several Onlineconverter for HMAC. I tried:

https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html

https://codebeautify.org/hmac-generator

When I convert the string to sign which Scratchpad generated (the 4 lines), I get an other SHA 256 HMAC then Scratchpad generated.

Also there are several Onlineconverter for Base64. I tried:

https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html

https://www.base64encode.org

When I convert the SHA 256 HMAC which Scratchpad generated, I get an other Base64-String then Scrathpad generated.

This confuses me. What I don't understand?

Other point:

Later I think I want to use GET and not POST. Do I get this right, that the string to sign for GET also has to be in 4 lines and not in one line as it would be executed later? That's how I understand the docu.

I used these links:
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_QueryString.html
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_SigningQueryRequest.html
https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html

Comment: Here are a few RFC 2104 compliant HMAC signature implementations (in the context of MWS) that could help you. 

https://github.com/integration-technology/amazon-mws-orders/blob/042e8cd5b10588a30150222bf9c91faf4f130b3c/src/main/java/com/amazonservices/mws/client/MwsUtl.java#L246-L270

https://github.com/czpython/python-amazon-mws/blob/master/mws/mws.py#L225-L229

https://github.com/eibbors/mws-js/blob/master/lib/mws.js#L114-L151

https://github.com/CPIGroup/phpAmazonMWS/blob/ddede7112bba41b9e6d837ec02b2d1309cd2f720/includes/classes/AmazonCore.php#L897-L922

Comment: Why are you trying to generate the HMAC? To use scratchpad, all you need is your seller id, access key and secret key (and any request data depending on the API endpoint). Scratchpad calculated the HMAC for you after you hit the send button. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have to write a program that uses MWS and can't use Java or any language you can find examples for. So first I wanted to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own questions.

---

Generate SHA256 with an Onlineconverter:

I suppose the Problem is the LF. The Onlineconverter maybe have problem with it. Maybe they use CRLF. Better don't try to check your SHA256 with Onlineconverters.

---

Generate base64 with an Onlineconverter:

The SHA256 Scratchpad shows is not the value you convert with base64. You have to convert the Hex-Value of the SHA256.

---

Query to sign with GET:

If you want to use GET, the query to sign has to look like the query to sign for POST. Also the four lines. Only swap POST with GET.